# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability"

Tags: android, google-play, google-api-client, arcore

What dependency needs to be added to solve the ClassNotFiundException for following error
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
  "com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability"